# How to build uImage?

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux, u-boot

I have zImage and kernel source. I did

```
make zImage
```

to generate the zImage.
When I flash this, the board won't boot up.
So how do I convert this to uImage which u-boot reads properly?
Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Install u-boot-tools. The command depends on your distribution. If you are using Debian/Ubuntu, it should look like

```
sudo apt-get install u-boot-tools
```

See [U-Boot documentation on tool installation](http://www.denx.de/wiki/view/DULG/UBootInstallTools)

---

make uImage

```
mkimage -A <arch> -O linux -T kernel -C none -a <load-address> -e <entry-point> -n "Linux kernel" -d arch/arm/boot/zImage uImage
```

or in the kernel source

```
make uImage
```

Comment: "make uImage" takes LOADADDR as a argument right? Where do i find this?

Comment: @Coder -- *"Where do i find this?"* -- See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31725605/building-kernel-uimage-using-loadaddr

Comment: Why do assume that the OP has a Debian/Ubuntu host/development system?  Your instructions/answer could be inappropriate/useless for other Linux distros such as Fedora.  You also presume that the OP's system is ARM.

Comment: Yeah for me, what this does is it creates the uImage exactly the same size as the zImage. Which CANNOT be right.