# U-boot start address?and u-boot.imx file contains?

Tags: linux-kernel, u-boot

I'm trying to understand embedded Linux principles and can't figure out addresses at u-boot output.

How can i find the starting address of U-boot?

For example, I have MX6-SabreSD board based on i.MX6 quad processor and I got following output from U-Boot:

```
U-Boot 2015.10-rc3 (Aug 10 2017 - 13:33:34)

CPU:   Freescale i.MX6Q rev1.2 at 792 MHz
Reset cause: POR
Board: MX6-SabreSD
DRAM:  1 GiB
MMC:   FSL_SDHC: 0
No panel detected: default to LDB-WVGA
Display: LDB-WVGA (800x480)
In:    serial
Out:   serial
Err:   serial
Net:   using phy at 6
FEC [PRIME]
Warning: FEC MAC addresses don't match:
Address in SROM is         00:c0:08:88:a5:e6
Address in environment is  00:c0:08:88:9c:ce

Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0 
Booting from mmc ...
4788388 bytes read in 303 ms (15.1 MiB/s)
## Booting kernel from Legacy Image at 12000000 ...
   Image Name:   Linux-3.0.35
   Image Type:   ARM Linux Kernel Image (uncompressed)
   Data Size:    4788324 Bytes = 4.6 MiB
   Load Address: 10008000
   Entry Point:  10008000
   Verifying Checksum ... OK
   Loading Kernel Image ... OK

Starting kernel ...
```

Comment: do you want the execution address of uboot in RAM?

Comment: Yeah, i need to find out the execution of u-boot address in RAM can u please help me?

Comment: Where the uboot stored? is it in flash?

Comment: In my case uboot is stored in SDCARD...

Comment: uboot relocation will happen in booting sequence.. we have to put debug prints there to find out the RAM location.

Comment: Yeah i tried but how to know the location of u-boot starting address...?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> U-boot start address?

The start address of U-Boot is specified using the symbol **CONFIG_SYS_TEXT_BASE**, which is typically defined in the board's configuration header file, i.e. **include/configs/.h**.
For an i.MX6 board, this value is typically 0x17800000.
But the executable will relocate itself to upper RAM.
The start address can be confirmed by reviewing the **System.map** or **u-boot.map** files if you have the build files.

> and u-boot.imx file contains?

The **u-boot.imx** file is the binary image used by the ROM boot code of i.MX SoCs.
It consists of the standard **u-boot.bin** executable, but is prepended with a 0xC00 byte header.
Details are in the U-Boot documentation file [**doc/README.imximage**](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/u-boot/latest/source/doc/README.imximage), which describes how to build the binary file and write it to media.

> How can i find the starting address of U-boot?

The start address appears to be stored at offset 0x4 (and the load address at 0x14) of the **u-boot.imx** file (although I'm unable to find confirmation).

The **u-boot.imx** file is stored on your SDcard starting at the third sector (i.e. byte offset 0x400).
See [embedded linux ARM booting address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39767332/embedded-linux-arm-booting-address/39779338#39779338) relating to writing the binary to the SDcard.