# Zynq Linux Kernel Load address

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, u-boot, zynq

I want to build linux for zed board. When I look into zynq-common.h file in u-boot/include/configs directory, I see that kernel_load_address is 0x02080000.

Why kernel load address is 0x02080000?
What is the logic of it?

I am using version 2018.01. 
Value that I mentioned is "kernel_load_address=0x2080000" in CONFIG_EXTRA_ENV_SETTINGS

Comment: I am using version 2018.01.Value that I mentioned is "kernel_load_address=0x2080000" in CONFIG_EXTRA_ENV_SETTINGS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that's the actual load address. UBoot should load it to 0x8000 by default. It could be modified, but you arn't going to want to do that through the header files.

(You shouldn't need to be looking at those files, especially not modifying them.)

If you want to build the kernel for the zedboard, I reccomend following either of these guides:
https://wiki.analog.com/resources/eval/user-guides/ad-fmcomms2-ebz/software/linux/zynq_2014r2
https://highlevel-synthesis.com/2016/10/31/how-to-compile-xilinx-linux-kernel-for-zynq/

You will also need the toolchains from Xilinx if you don't want to build the kernel on platform which will take 4-6 or more hours (I have had to do it before, not fun).

Comment: "I want to build linux for zed board" -> I suggest starting from a known working configuration. Buildroot has a defconfig for the zedboard and in a few commands you'll get a booting SD card image to start from. The yocto meta-xilinx layer also has a zedboard machine conf. Both are simpler and more reusable for a real job than following the tutorials IMO.

Comment: I have already built linux kernel before. But I didn't understand logic of 0x2080000. I use 0x08008000 for TI's AM335x processors. Because starting address of ram is 0x08000000 in AM335x and I add 32k offset to this address.

Answer (score 0):

> Value that I mentioned is "kernel_load_address=0x2080000" in CONFIG_EXTRA_ENV_SETTINGS

That particular environment variable is not the mainline version of U-Boot.  So apparently you are using a custom version.

The use of that env variable is likely to locate the kernel image with an input command in main memory.  Since this is an ARM board the kernel image would be a zImage or uImage (which would contain a zImage).
The zImage is capable of uncompressing itself and relocating the kernel image to its proper load address for actual execution.
That final load address is typically the start of physical memory plus 0x8000.  See [Building kernel uImage using LOADADDR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31725605/building-kernel-uimage-using-loadaddrilding-kernel-uimage-using-loadaddr)

Since the kernel will be relocated during decompression, this intermediate memory address used by U-boot for reading in the compressed kernel image is not crucial.  The uncompression code attached to the zImage is position independent, so loading the zImage into memory is flexible.  As long as the zImage resides in memory higher than the kernel's actual loadaddress, there is no issue (i.e. an extra relocation).